# Play! 2 Framework doesn't recognize Apache port forwarding

Tags: apache, .htaccess, playframework, assets

I've just finished developing my first Play! 2 application and have to deploy it to my school server. The application runs on port :9002 and we use port forwarding in order to have a nicer URL (e.g. "*some.server.com/**MyPlayApp**/*" instead of "*some.server.com:**9002**/*").

I'm starting Play! on the server by using "**start 9002**" and everything is working fine. The only problem is that Play! doesn't seem to know about the port forwarding and all my assets (all CSS, JS etc) cannot get loaded. They should be loaded from "*some.server.com/**MyPlayApp**/assets/stylesheets/main.css*", but what Play! tries to do is load them from "*some.server.com/assets/stylesheets/main.css*". And of course all other in-app URLs are crashing because they're trying to access "*some.server.com/section*" instead of "*some.server.com/**MyPlayApp**/section*".

I tried specifying a **baseUrl** in the config file, I tried adding an **.htaccess** file on the server with *RewriteEngine On* and *RewriteBase /MyPlayApp/*, I tried modifying the route for the assets and a few other "tricks" to no avail. I have a dirty hack in mind but I would really like to do this the Play! way if possible.

Thanks for any help or suggestions!

Comment: Solved it? I'm in a similar situation, and need help!